# Buttons wont work

Tags: html, css, button

Here is our desperate try to make the buttons work. The BUTTON worked before i added the other one. please help. We also had difficulties with making the buttons look different but that is fixed now. (Its just telling me to text some more so thats the reason im writing this. this aint important. How are you doing today?)

```css
   .Button {
    background-color: darkcyan;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
 font-family: hacked;
 
 
}

  .sub {
  position: relative;
}
.itmHolder {
  position: relative;
}

  
  
  .itmHolder:nth-child(2),
.itmHolder:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.og {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <title>Our Future</title>
 </head>
 <!--Baggrunds farve-->
 <body bgcolor="#212f3c">
 
 <!--Hovedskriften-->
     <font size=40><center><h1 style="font-family:blowbrush;">Future</font></center></h1><form action="side2.html">
  
  
   <div class="og">
  <div class="itmHolder">

    <div class="sub">
      <button type="button" class="Button">About us<form action="side2.html"></button>
      <button type="button" class="Button">Buy now<form action="buynow.html"></button>
    </div>
</div>
  
  
  <br></br>
 </body>
</html>
  <picture>
  <!--Billede-->
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
 <center><img src="CSfU23PXAAEA8et.jpg" alt="Matrix" style="width:auto;" border="5"><center/>
 <br></br>
 <br></br>
<!--Youtube video-->
 <center><iframe width="700" height="400"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?playlist=XGSy3_Czz8k&loop=1"></center></iframe>
</picture>
```

Comment: You need to actually explain your problem. And when it tells you to add more text, that doesn't mean you should add some irrelevant spam to your question. How is anyone supposed to help you when you haven't even said what you're trying to accomplish, other than "make the buttons work"?

Comment: Considering those will only work on your directory structure and I have no clue what they are supposed to do, how would I know how they are supposed to work?

Comment: Buddy, why don't you start with basic html & css tutorial?

Comment: I already told you. The buttons wont work. I'm trying to make one button go to the other site.

Comment: @EmalSahari My car isn't working, why?

Answer (score 0):

You havnt closed your form tag and you have it in the wrong place. Adjust your code:

```
    <div class="sub">
        <form action="side2.html" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" class="Button" value="About us">
        </form>
        <form action="buynow.html" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" class="Button" value="Buy now">
        </form>
    </div>
```

OR If you prefer not to use forms, use the `<a>` tag:

```
    <div class="sub">
       <button type="button" class="Button"><a href="side2.html">About us</a></button>
       <button type="button" class="Button"><a href="buynow.html">Buy now</a></button>
    </div>
```

Comment: When i do this my buttons dont go side by side but on top of each other

Comment: Using what? The forms or the `<a>` tag>

Comment: No the top one with the form.

Comment: I dont want the <a> tag because then i have to click on the text

Comment: No you dont, you can put this in your CSS: `a { display:block; }` and that will make the link span the whole of your button.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use buttons to navigate through pages. You can do this instead:

```
<a href="buynow.html"> Buy Now </a>
```

Then style *a* however much you like.

Buttons are used with *JavaScript* in case you need to pass an *onClick* action.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used the `<form>` tag in the right way in the below code part

```
<div class="sub">
      <button type="button" class="Button">About us<form action="side2.html"></button>
      <button type="button" class="Button">Buy now<form action="buynow.html"></button>
    </div>
```

Try this way

```
<div class="sub">
   <form action="side2.html">
      <button type="submit" class="Button">About us</button>
   </form>
   <form action="buynow.html">
      <button type="submit" class="Button">Buy now</button>
   </form>
    </div>
```

else try this alternate way

```
<div class="sub">
  <a href="side2.html" class="Button">About us</a>
  <a href="buynow.html" class="Button">Buy now</a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.